# How can I trigger the reverse video mode after Emacs has started?

Tags: emacs

I know I can start Emacs with the "--reverse-video" command line option. But is there a way to get the same result after starting Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

Try `M-x invert-face <RET> default <RET>`.  That should get you pretty close.